# How can I make sure all my observables have completed before showing a toast message?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have a scenario in which I have to make some api calls, then show some toast messages informing the user if the calls succeeded or failed. In the code below, the `processSaveResponses` method gets called before the observable's are resolved. The `processSaveResponses` method is responsible for displaying the toast messages. I understand this is expected behavior, since observable's are asynchronous, but I don't know how to "wait" unit the observable's have finished.

The `deliveryPreferencesService.save` and `deliveryPreferencesService.saveAutoEnroll` methods are independent of each other, but `deliveryPreferencesService.saveAutoEnroll` should not be called if `deliveryPreferencesService.save` failed.

```js
  private saveChanges(changeSet: DeliveryPreferencesChangeSet) {

    let deliveryPrefernceResult;
    let saveAutoEnroll = true;

    const { accountPreferences: accountPreferenceChanges, autoEnrollPreferences: autoEnrollPreferenceChanges } = changeSet.changes;

    if (accountPreferenceChanges.length) {
      this.deliveryPreferencesService.save(accountPreferenceChanges).
        subscribe(
          () => deliveryPrefernceResult = true,
          () => saveAutoEnroll = false);
    }

    if (autoEnrollPreferenceChanges.length) {
      if (saveAutoEnroll) {
        this.deliveryPreferencesService.saveAutoEnroll(autoEnrollPreferenceChanges).
          subscribe(
            () => console.log('save auto enroll completed'),
            () => saveAutoEnroll = false);
      }
    }

    this.processSaveResponses([{ success: deliveryPrefernceResult }, {success: saveAutoEnroll}]);
  }
```

Here is the code for the `processSaveResponses` :

```
    if (every(responses, ['success', false])) {
      this.showErrorToastr(this.ALL_CHANGES_FAILURE_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (every(responses, ['success', true])) {
      this.originalPreferences = cloneDeep(this.currentPreferences);
      this.onChange.next();
      this.showSuccessToastr(this.ALL_CHANGES_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
      if ((responses[0] as any).success) {
        this.originalPreferences.accountPreferenceSets = cloneDeep(this.currentPreferences.accountPreferenceSets);
        this.showSuccessToastr(this.DELIVERY_PREFERENCES_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
        this.showErrorToastr(this.AUTO_ENROLL_FAILURE_MESSAGE);
      } else {
        this.originalPreferences.autoEnrollPreferences = cloneDeep(this.currentPreferences.autoEnrollPreferences);
        this.showSuccessToastr(this.AUTO_ENROLL_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
        this.showErrorToastr(this.DELIVERY_PREFERENCES_FAILURE_MESSAGE);
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using rxjs version 5.5.2.

Comment: you can change observable to promise and then wait for the response. and then complete your calls.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `switchMap` as described here. I guess it can be used in your case.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

```
this.deliveryPreferencesService.save(accountPreferenceChanges)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(x => this.deliveryPreferencesService.saveAutoEnroll(autoEnrollPreferenceChanges))
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    // TODO something
  })
```

In this case `this.deliveryPreferencesService.saveAutoEnroll(autoEnrollPreferenceChanges)` will be called only after succeeded `this.deliveryPreferencesService.save(accountPreferenceChanges)`

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but ```this.deliveryPreferencesService.saveAutoEnroll``` can be called without ```this.deliveryPreferencesService.save```.

Comment: No, this.deliveryPreferencesService.saveAutoEnroll will be called only after calling deliveryPreferencesService.save(accountPreferenceChanges). If deliveryPreferencesService.save(accountPreferenceChanges) is not called, deliveryPreferencesService.save(accountPreferenceChanges) won't be called.

Comment: They will be called strictly consistently

Comment: What I meant in my previous comment was in my scenario, the ```this.deliveryPreferencesService.saveAutoEnroll``` can be called alone IF ```autoEnrollPreferenceChanges.length``` is greater than zero AND ```accountPreferenceChanges.length``` is equal to zero.

Comment: @broke, you could start with an [`iif`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/iif/) , like `iif(condition, save(), of(undefined))` and then `switchMap` to `saveAutoEnroll`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **zip**

```
import { of, zip } from 'rxjs';



const x1$ = of('Hello');
const x2$ = of('World!');
const x3$ = of('Goodbye');
const x4$ = of('World!');

const subscription = zip(x1$, x2$, x3$, x4$).subscribe( res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

> ["Hello", "World!", "Goodbye", "World!"]

OK

Comment: Not sure how this would help. I don't want to call ```saveAutoEnroll``` if ```deliveryPreferencesService.save``` failed

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've got. You can do it by using async\await with promises. Now it should work by your scenario.

```
  private async saveChanges(changeSet: DeliveryPreferencesChangeSet) {
    const { accountPreferences: accountPreferenceChanges, autoEnrollPreferences: autoEnrollPreferenceChanges } = changeSet.changes;

    if (accountPreferenceChanges.length) {
      await this.deliveryPreferencesService.save(accountPreferenceChanges).toPromise();
    }

    if (autoEnrollPreferenceChanges.length) {

        await this.deliveryPreferencesService.saveAutoEnroll(autoEnrollPreferenceChanges).toPromise();
    }

    this.processSaveResponses([{ success: true }, {success: true}]);
  }
```

More about async/await in TS
https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/async-await-in-typescript-tutorial/